# How to host multiple react apps from a single Netlify project?

Tags: reactjs, hosting, netlify

Currently, I'm using a repository with at least 4 different apps. Its structure is something like this

```
root_folder/
  app1/
  app2/
  app3/
  app4/
```

Where each subdirectory is a react application. How do I use the Netlify Monorepo feature mentioned [here](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/monorepos/)? I want to use it in such a way that all the apps map under a single domain, eg: example.com, example.com/app1, example.com/app2 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

### Multi-site way:

Setup all the 4 repos as 4 different websites in the Netlify UI. You can specify the base directory for each and that should work fine. Then, you can create a 5th site which would make use of Netlify's Proxy rewrites: https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/

In other words, the 5th website would be like the main website used to route to all other websites. Your `netlify.toml` in the 5th website would look something like:

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/path1/*"
  to = "https://site-from-app-1.netlify.app/"
  status = 200
```

and more such rewrites for the rest of the apps.

### Single-site way:

You'd have to make your build command like:

```
cd ./app1/ && npm run build && cp -R ./build/ ../dist/app1/ && cd ../app2/ && npm run build && cp -R ./build/ ../dist/app2/ && cd ../app3/ ...
```

Basically, you'd have to make a super long build command to `cd` into each directory, build the app, copy the built files into a single folder which you'd set as the publish folder in Netlify.

Comment: In the first approach, I would have to use different domains right? Is there a way to keep all sites within the same project with the same domain? but different paths?

Comment: You'd have to use a single domain on site 5. All the other sites can use the default Netlify subdomain and you'd have to use rewrites as explained.

As far as the second question is concerned (all sites within the same project), I've mentioned that in single-site way.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot Hrishikesh!